# How can I calculate potential space savings with btrfs compression?

Tags: btrfs, compression

I'm not currently using compression with my btrfs-formatted disk, but am wondering how much space I'd save if I did enable it.  Short of actually enabling compression on the disk and comparing the free space before and after (or less destructively but more resource intensively, copying all my data to another btrfs-formatted disk with compression enabled), is there any way of getting an estimate of what the space savings would be for a given compression algorithm and level?  If the btrfs tools can't do this, is there perhaps some third-party tool that will iterate over all the files in my system to do a dry run of the compression, skipping all the same uncompressable files that btrfs itself would skip?

Comment: https://btrfs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Compression.html

Answer (score 1):

btrfs supports three compressors: gzip, lzo, and zstd. You almost certainly wouldn't want to use gzip (both slower and less efficient at compression than the alternatives); LZO and ZSTD are usually very comparable at high speed settings.

So, run with `zstd`; the default compression level for zstd in btrfs is 3, though levels 1 to 15 are available. `zstd -3 -v < infile > /dev/null` will show you how the compression rate when compressing that file at level 3; replace `3` with anything between 1 and 15 to get a feeling for the speed / compression ratio tradeoff you're doing (note that this is done single-threaded; I think the kernel btrfs compressor might actually be multithreaded, so add `-T0` to your compression settings to see how fast you get with more cores).

Note that this isn't any "smarter" than enabling compression and `cat`ing the content of a file to a new one; btrfs will not automatically compress all existing files, just new ones.

Note that I'd be a bit careful with what filesystems you do that with. For example, I don't know whether GRUB's btrfs driver supports reading compressed files. And: less-than-commonly used on-disk format options in btrfs have, in the past, lead to data corruption (for example, you might not want to use btrfs-internal RAID 5, though the userland tools don't warn you about it at all). So, If you need high read performance, or if you have little space but very compressible files that are not duplicates of each other, try compression, but do it on something that you have a backup of.

Comment: I'm afraid this doesn't actually answer my question. I know that I could write a program to loop through my filesystem, piping each file through a compression program that uses the same back-end method as btrfs, and maintaining a running total of the space savings. The question is whether such a program already exists, and moreover is smart enough to skip the same files that btrfs itself would.

Comment: You're right, you'd have to apply the command listed above to each file and do your own accounting. I was assuming you'd want to be doing this on a representative sample of the type of file that occupies most of your volume; as said, not sure you'd want to do this on your system volume, and so I assume you had "human expert knowledge" of the data. The problem with testing compression of the whole FS: The quickest way to know how large a file is after compression is compressing it; an external tool that's not part of btrfs itself can't know which files are already de-duplicated, which of course

Comment: means they can only be compressed once. So, whatever you do, the result would be approximate, so that you could just as well go, and base your estimate on a smaller, hand-picked sample, to be honest :) The question for a read/write file system really becomes: what is the quality of space saving or read performance estimate that you hoped for? You can't predict what data you'll write in the future. So a "Oh yeah, standard compression test corpuses compress this kind of data by 25%" is about as useful as you'll get an estimate, I'm afraid